# Infer generic parameter of explicit interface implementation in class after migrating to 3.9.2

Tags: typescript

## Simplified version

In the following code typescript 3.8.3 produces [`type WhatExt = ISomeExt`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEAmmD2IA8AKgKIAekIAzsHgHzIDeAsAFDLvITkQiZEDKAWzAALWgApKwkQC5khIaICUchdOQAyeWQrU8AblYBfVq1CRYiFKn45BEHY1YdkuW-YDyo6IRGgA5uIqyABuOMCYhiwmLKwIADZwlJTI7hBYuCDIwIIADvEQ9uApGNh4+DZ2DuT0zGwcuQCuAEbxwAic3LwC0hJSoqqKIsFqoppoaY51Li5QEGCNUFn9IshJ8kPjlfY6zhwxMaxgAJ65KADqInBgjgC8qVUZeJ0UmCVPBKAw0PL0APzyZByEAQELQIA), but when I switch to typescript 3.9.2 I get [`type WhatExt = unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEAmmD2IA8AKgKIAekIAzsHgHzIDeAsAFDLvITkQiZEDKAWzAALWgApKwkQC5khIaICUchdOQAyeWQrU8AblYBfVq1CRYiFKn45BEHY1YdkuW-YDyo6IRGgA5uIqyABuOMCYhiwmLKwIADZwlJTI7hBYuCDIwIIADvEQ9uApGNh4+DZ2DuT0zGwcuQCuAEbxwAic3LwC0hJSoqqKIsFqoppoaY51Li5QEGCNUFn9IshJ8kPjlfY6zhwxMaxgAJ65KADqInBgjgC8qVUZeJ0UmCVPBKAw0PL0APzyZByEAQELQIA). How can I fix that?

```
interface IAddon<TExtension> {
    extend<TSmth>(smth: TSmth): TSmth & TExtension;
}

interface ISomeExt {
    doSomeOtherThing(): void;
}

class SomeAddon implements IAddon<ISomeExt> {
    public extend<TSmth>(smth: TSmth): TSmth & ISomeExt {
        return smth as TSmth & ISomeExt
    }
}

type WhatExt = SomeAddon extends IAddon<infer T> ? T : never
```

## Original question

This [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.8.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWyDeAsAFDJnIAmA9lrgBQCUAXMgG5XAUDcJAviSTABPAA4pUAQQrUQAYTBUoAHgAqUmcggAPSCAoBnNOqohVAUR0QQ+4CYB8AGmQqLum-eQBeZCAgB3ZEYvO2djEB5iElBIWERxMPNLa1sQLwJeEKJScm1dClVaPFyrAzRCuzp9bBwWFULmZ0LkADJnVyt3cL4BYmExZASXJM6Q70lpE3lFJXGZRLcUxzbhxYiSBAAbOH1DQoAhAFdgDYpoVU0k0oxqtOvcTJJyZBEDgCMN4AQLvPmKuAmQCxBq47AwCI8nuQoBAwAcoKlcMBDNtkHAQEJUbtqodjqdlCoWsswHYIk9+JFsmQXu9PshXkcTkEspCoTC4akQAcNhtMaj0byVKTyOTyVFwNB4EgylRMBBXODKZQaDKIAB5XDQFQ4UAAc0YLHYnAiouIm22uxVYWQwEwIg2EFl4EMsxMM3QKpBCqe1I+X2KegKN39V3KlWqtXqXpZyGhsPhyCquAFTVaGA9OghZBFPVYcCgyC0aV8AX2DLxjAAdMG6O7ZWEGBX6bjGD0tBXqIUW8Q2x2VeqcJrtSA9QwgA) is fine for TS 3.8.3:

```
interface ISmth {
    doSmth(): void;
}

type IAddonCtor<TAddon extends IAddon<TExtension>, TExtension> = new () => TAddon;

interface IAddon<TExtension = {}> {
    extend<TSmth extends ISmth>(smth: TSmth): TSmth & TExtension;
}

type Addon<TExtension> = IAddonCtor<IAddon<TExtension>, TExtension>;

class SmthBuilder<T extends ISmth = ISmth> {
    public extend<TExt>(addon: Addon<TExt>) {
        return this as any as SmthBuilder<T & TExt>;
    }

    public build() {
        return null as any as T;
    }
}

interface ISomeExt {
    doSomeOtherThing(): void;
}

class SomeAddon implements IAddon<ISomeExt> {
    public extend<TSmth extends ISmth>(smth: TSmth) {
        return smth as TSmth & ISomeExt
    }
}

var x = new SmthBuilder().extend(SomeAddon).build()

x.doSmth()
x.doSomeOtherThing()
```

Look at the last 3 lines:

```
var x = new SmthBuilder().extend(SomeAddon).build()
```

In this line `extend` is inferred as

> ```
> (method) SmthBuilder<ISmth>.extend<ISomeExt>(addon: IAddonCtor<IAddon<ISomeExt>, ISomeExt>): SmthBuilder<ISmth & ISomeExt>
> ```

Note `extend<ISomeExt>` that returns `SmthBuilder<ISmth & ISomeExt>`.

So in the last 2 lines I can call both methods:

```
x.doSmth()
x.doSomeOtherThing()
```

Now I'm trying to switch to TS 3.9.2 and with [the same code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=36&ssc=21&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWyDeAsAFDJnIAmA9lrgBQCUAXMgG5XAUDcJAviSTABPAA4pUAQQrUQAYTBUoAHgAqUmcggAPSCAoBnNOqohVAUR0QQ+4CYB8AGmQqLum-eQBeZCAgB3ZEYvO2djEB5iElBIWERxMPNLa1sQLwJeEKJScm1dClVaPFyrAzRCuzp9bBwWFULmZ0LkADJnVyt3cL4BYmExZASXJM6Q70lpE3lFJXGZRLcUxzbhxYiSBAAbOH1DQoAhAFdgDYpoVU0k0oxqtOvcTJJyZBEDgCMN4AQLvPmKuAmQCxBq47AwCI8nuQoBAwAcoKlcMBDNtkHAQEJUbtqodjqdlCoWsswHYIk9+JFsmQXu9PshXkcTkEspCoTC4akQAcNhtMaj0byVKTyOTyVFwNB4EgylRMBBXODKZQaDKIAB5XDQFQ4UAAc0YLHYnAiouIm22uxVYWQwEwIg2EFl4EMsxMM3QKpBCqe1I+X2KegKN39V3KlWqtXqXpZyGhsPhyCquAFTVaGA9OghZBFPVYcCgyC0aV8AX2DLxjAAdMG6O7ZWEGBX6bjGD0tBXqIUW8Q2x2VeqcJrtSA9QwgA) I'm getting inference

> ```
> (method) SmthBuilder<ISmth>.extend<unknown>(addon: IAddonCtor<IAddon<unknown>, unknown>): SmthBuilder<ISmth>
> ```

So `extend<unknown>` returns `SmthBuilder<ISmth>` so in the last line I'm unable to call

```
x.doSomeOtherThing()
```

because of

> Property 'doSomeOtherThing' does not exist on type 'ISmth'.

What's wrong? How can I get back inferrence of `extend<ISomeExt>` to make it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simplified fix

[fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEAmmD2IA8AKgKIAekIAzsHgHzIDeAsAFDLvITkQiZEDKAWzAALWgApKwkQC5khIaICUchdOQAyeWQrU8AblYBfVq1CRYiFKn45BEHY1YdkuW-YDyo6IRGgA5uIqyABuOMCYhiwmLKwIADZwlJTI7hBYuCDIwIIADvEQ9uApGNh4+DZ2DuT0zGwcuQCuAEbxwAic3LwC0hJSoqqKIsFqoppoaY51Li5QEGCNUFn9IshJ8kPjlfY6zhwxMaxgAJ65KADqInBgjgC8yABK84sghKcQ+GkZeADaAERcCiYP4AXVoQA)

```
type WhatExt = ReturnType<SomeAddon["extend"]>
```

## Original fix

[fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUC2YAWyDeAsAFDJnIAmA9lrgBQCUAXMgG5XAUDcJAviSTABPAA4pUAQQrUQAYTBUoAHgAqUmcggAPSCAoBnNOqohVAUR0QQ+4CYB8AGmQqLum-eQBeZCAgB3ZEYvO2djEB5iElBIWERxMPNLa1sQLwJeEKJScm1dClVaPFyrAzRCuzp9bBwWFULmZ0LkADJnVyt3cL4BYmExZASXJM6Q70lpE3lFJXGZRLcUxzbhxYiSBAAbOH1DQoAhAFdgDYpoVU0k0oxqtOvcTJJyZBEDgCMN4AQLvKUAVW+SoYEnAQEI7BU4BMQCxfgwCI8nuQoBAwAcoKlcMBDNtkCChLjdtVDsdTsoVC1kAAlFFokAqUQQGbWMAgpD0sR-OwAbQARMU9DyALrgiJPfiRbJkF7vT7IV5HE5BLKIpE09E+A4bDYE3GgnUqUXkcXiqLgaDwJBlKiYCCueGSyg0a0QADyuGgKhwoAA5owWOxOBETcRNttds6wshgJgRBsIDbwIZZiYZuhna4Hg7pR8vvz8nUbnmk+VKtVavV7SqyMjUeqqrh9U1Whh0zoEWRjT1WHAoMgtGlfAF9grSYwAHR5uhpm1hBhj+Ukxg9LRj6iFJfEFdr51unAer0gX0MIA)

```
public extend<U extends Addon<any>>(addon: U) {
    return this as any as SmthBuilder<T & ReturnType<InstanceType<U>["extend"]>>;
}
```